# Need to find the difference between two timestamp in hours using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle9i

```
SELECT MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN CLKTRANTYPE_ID = 1
    THEN MIN((TO_CHAR (CLKTRANPRO_TIME,'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')))
  END) AS MIN_TIME ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN CLKTRANTYPE_ID = 2
    THEN MAX((TO_CHAR(CLKTRANPRO_PROC_DT,'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')) )
  END) AS MAX_TIME 
FROM CLOCK_TRAN_PROCESSED
WHERE WRKS_ID =1652201
GROUP BY WRKS_ID,CLKTRANTYPE_ID;
```

Above is my Query and i need to find the difference between MAX_TIME and MIN_TIME in hours format . I tried using extract and (-) but nothing working for me. Please help me to find the difference in Hours format.

Comment: There is no logic to get the difference....other than getting Max and Min.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you convert the values to strings to get the difference?

```
select (extract(day from max(CLKTRANPRO_PROC_DT) - min(CLKTRANPRO_TIME)) * 24 +
        extract(hour from max(CLKTRANPRO_PROC_DT) - min(CLKTRANPRO_TIME))
       ) as diff_hours
```

Comment: SELECT extract(HOUR from (  MAX(
   CASE
    WHEN CLKTRANTYPE_ID = 2
    THEN MAX((CLKTRANPRO_PROC_DT)) 
  END) - MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN CLKTRANTYPE_ID = 1
    THEN MIN(CLKTRANPRO_TIME)
  END) )) DIFF 
FROM CLOCK_TRAN_PROCESSED
WHERE WRKS_ID =1652201
GROUP BY WRKS_ID,CLKTRANTYPE_ID;

Comment: Used the above code got "ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source" Error

Answer (score 0):

Difference in hours

```
select 24 * (to_date('2017-07-07 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
             - to_date('2017-07-07 19:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) diff_in_hours 
       from dual;
```

Result for above query should be 2.5 hrs

Simple way to get difference

```
select Date1 - Date2 from your_Table;
```